# accidentally associated .Dat Files to open with notpad

Tags: windows-7

Well, I was trying to edit the .Dat file for a game "Oregon trail 5th edition" when I associated .Dat file with notepad. Now all my .Dat Files have adopted the notepad icon and only opens with notepad. I have a windows 7 Home Premium laptop and would like some help on this issue.

Comment: Do you remember with which program .dat file was associated before this mess?

Comment: .dat has no default file association. On a clean install of W7 there is no association with any program unless you set one or another program did, what is your specific issue with dat files?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the registry.

Search "`.DAT`" under this key.

Click on this key and delete the (Default) value.

Or you can simply use this [tool](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unassociate-file-types-windows-7-vista/).